# I am trying to return a certain values in each row which depend on whether different values in that row are already in a different table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, row

I'm still a n00b at SQL and am running into a snag.  What I have is an initial selection of certain IDs into a temp table based upon certain conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM ICC
WHERE ICC_Code = 1 AND ICC_State = 'CA'
```

Later in the query I SELECT a different and much longer listing of IDs along with other data from other tables.  That SELECT is about 20 columns wide and is my result set.  What I would like to be able to do is add an extra column to that result set with each value of that column either TRUE or FALSE.  If the ID in the row is in #TEMPTABLE the value of the additional column should read TRUE.  If not, FALSE.  This way the added column will ready TRUE or FALSE on each row, depending on if the ID in each row is in `#TEMPTABLE`.

The second SELECT would be something like:

```
SELECT ID,
       ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
       ...
       NEWCOLUMN
FROM ...
```

NEWCOLUMN's value for each row would depend on whether the ID in that row returned is in #TEMPTABLE.

Does anyone have any advice here?

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

If you left join to the #TEMPTABLE you'll get a NULL where the ID's don't exist

```
SELECT ID,
       ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
       ...
       T.ID IS NOT NULL AS NEWCOLUMN -- Gives 1 or 0 or True/false as a bit
FROM ... X
LEFT JOIN #TEMPTABLE T
ON T.ID = X.ID -- DEFINE how the two rows can be related unquiley
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to LEFT JOIN your results query to #TEMPTABLE ON ID, this will give you the ID if there is one and `NULL` if there isn't, if you want 1 or 0 this would do it (For SQL Server) ISNULL(#TEMPTABLE.ID,0)<>0.

A few notes on coding for performance:

1. By definition an ID column is unique so the `DISTINCT` is redundant and causes unnecisary processing (unless it is an ID from another table)
2. Why would you store this to a temporary table rather than just using it in the query directly?

Comment: Hey Dale, I spoke very loosely in terminology.  It isn't a true ID column.  Also, I was thinking of querying directly and joining on what I had already put in the temp table.  I'll probably end up switching over to your recommendation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union and a subquery.

```
Select . . . . , 'TRUE'
From . . .
Where ID in 
(Select id FROM #temptable)
UNION
SELECT . . . , 'FALSE'
FROM . . .
WHERE ID NOT in 
(Select id FROM #temptable)
```

So the top part, SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ID IN (*Subquery*), does a SELECT if the ID is in your temptable.

The bottom part does a SELECT if the ID is **not** in the temptable.

The UNION operator joins the two results nicely, since both SELECT statements will return the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what someone else was saying with Union, just do something like so

```
SELECT id, TRUE AS myColumn FROM  `table1` 
UNION 
SELECT id, FALSE AS myColumn FROM  `table2`
```